# DNA Sequencing and genotyping

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing, genomics

Before going to the details of the question let me post a few other details-
(I posted something similar and got no useful answers-probably because I didn't explain things properly or something else)-
1. My background is not genetics.
2.I am not interested in knowing how dna sequencing or genotyping is done.
3. I am interested just in the nature of the results as in-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_sequencing#/media/File:Radioactive_Fluorescent_Seq.jpg
Now coming to the question- Humans have two sets of chromosome in each cell. So if I say sequencing chromosome1,what does that actually mean? Which of the two chromosome's gets sequenced?
Of genotyping-do comparison take place between two+two=four chromosome1's? 
Or is my entire undertanding flawed?

Comment: You should first read up on the linked pages on the other question. If you have more questions (to incite curiosity was the point of the answer), you should ask in the comments section. If you think that your question was wrongly worded you can reword the question mentioning UPDATE. And lastly, you are touching too many topics. Until further clarification I am marking this as a duplicate to the first one which you asked.

Comment: Double question. Will be merged with http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50755/sequencing-two-strands-of-dna