# Two sets of chromosome and the sequencing output

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing, genomics

Humans have two sets of chromosomes that are not connected in each cell. Am I correct?

I assume while sequencing DNA both of these sets have to be sequenced and the output have to be provided in some order - i.e., paternal set followed by maternal or vice versa, though it may not be possible to know which is paternal and which is maternal.

(I know there are different types of sequencing techniques and output may differ depending on the technique. Here I am speaking of the general case). I tried clarify this question myself. But may be this is such a basic thing that no one seems to touch upon this aspect.

Comment: Note for observers: [previous question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50755/sequencing-two-strands-of-dna) as referred to.

Comment: For many biological research questions it is not important to know, if the sequence comes from the paternal or maternal chromosome. - However - as you pointed out - there are different approaches of obtaining the sequences. Some of them would allow to distinguish different chromosomes (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contig  ).   In practice: if you would like to know if a variant of a gene comes from the father or mother it is easier / cheaper to sequence them (or do some other faster/ cheaper test on them).

Comment: If an answer given to a question is unclear, you can do two things: Either write a comment or adapt your question. Showing the kind of attitude you do "I don't understand the current answer and don't care to do so" is actually insulting towards the people which invest time to write an answer. Actually not the best idea.

Comment: I believe the question boils down to simply: How are heterozygous results reported from the sequence alignment process?

Answer (score 4):

This is very similar to your previous questions, but apparently you are not understanding the explanations we are giving, so I'll try again, by giving a (hopefully not-too-technical) explanation of how next-generation genomic sequencing works. To avoid confusion, we'll assume we're working with human samples.

First, many individual cells are collected (the number depends on the application, it can range from 1 cell to millions or more), and their DNA is collected. This process destroys the cells, and all of the copies of all of the chromosomes are mixed together. As mentioned in your other question, there *is no possible way to determine which chromosomal sequence is maternal, and which is paternal*. Scientists typically don't even think about this.

Next, the collected DNA sample is purified and broken down into small pieces, then ligated to certain adapters to label them for the sequencing reaction. The sample is then amplified in a standard [PCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymerase_chain_reaction) to create starting material that is many times more plentiful than before. This is the DNA library.

Finally, the sample is ready for sequencing. What exactly happens next depends on which sequencer you're using - Illumina, Ion Torrent, 454, or SOLiD are the most frequently-used instrument brands. Within each brand, Illumina for example, there are multiple different kinds of sequencing.

However, we'll just gloss over all that and get right to the output - the instrument produces a file consisting of "reads" from the reaction. These reads are DNA sequences consisting of As, Ts, Gs, and Cs - the "letters" (also known as "bases") of DNA. The lengths of the reads vary by technology and instrument, generally in the range of 100 to 700 bases. One machine, though - the PacBio RS II, can produce high-quality reads up to 14,000 bases, although to my knowledge it is not in widespread use.

Here is where the computers come in. The individual reads overlap each other to varying degrees, depending on the quality of information you're seeking and whether or not you're looking for rare events, such as a small population of mutated cells taken from a heterogeneous tumor. For our purposes, we'll say our sequencing run resulted in a 25-fold overlap, meaning each base in the original DNA sequence of the sample donor was sequenced an average of 25 different times. The computers can then "align" the sequences, either just among themselves, without a template, or, more commonly, to a pre-existing sequence template, such as a [reference genome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_genome). Eventually, the computer will spit out two sequences - the forward and the reverse strand (although typically you'd just pick one strand, and use the reverse strand for error-checking). This sequence is the **average** sequence of the chromosome, or other region of DNA being targeted.

[image]

<sup>*From Wikimedia Commons: [Mapping Reads.png](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mapping_Reads.png)*</sup>

However, one can pretty easily detect mutations, such as single nucleotide polymorphisms ([SNPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism)), deletions, insertions, etc. In the case of a SNP (pronounced "snip"), one [allele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) of a gene has one sequence on one chromosome (lets say ATTC**G**TAAC) while another allele of a gene on the other chromosome has a single-base change (ATTC**T**TAAC, for example, where the **G** was changed to a **T**).

The point, directly relating to your question, is this: The final sequence that eventually comes out after all the computer wrangling is *a single sequence* with certain areas that may differ from chromosome to chromosome, or cell to cell in the original sample. There is **no way** to determine if the **G** in our example above was on the maternal or paternal chromosome. There is *also* no way to tell if, 20,000 bases down the line, another mutation is on the *same* chromosome as the **G**, because no single read can (currently) span that entire length. You might have a pretty good chance of determining that if the other mutation is, for example, 300 bases away, because many technologies can perform high-quality reads longer than that, so you'd just have to find the individual ones that contain both positions.

I know this was a little long-winded, but hopefully I was able to answer your question.

Comment: Matt, if the guy didn't understand first time, why did you give such a long and technical answer second time? It would be enough to say what's in your final paragraph that he'll probably never get to. i.e. The result is a mixture of both chromosomes, so we only know if the sequence at any point is the same for both or different. (And because of crossing over there's no such thing as a maternal or paternal.)

Comment: @David I had to try - the answers to the previous question weren't *that* great, and while the OP said s/he didn't care about the details of sequencing, I figured that actually explaining how sequencing works in general terms would help them understand why there is no "order" of which chromosome comes first. And, I had some free time, so it wasn't that big of a deal.

Comment: @David regarding crossing over: that happens during meiosis in the parent, when germ cells are being formed. The egg is haploid, as is the sperm, but after they join the chromosomes do not cross over again.

Comment: Whoops. Shows how little I know about classical biology.

Comment: @MattDMo Could you please explain the last paragraph of your answer? You said (in your example) that we can't determine the G in our sequence was on the maternal or paternal chromosome. Won't both the alleles on the homologous chromosomes be sequenced? If yes, do we have sequences of both the chromosome (be it or be it not distinguished) in the final sequence? I don't know the intricate details on this subject, but it occurred to me whether or not we have a single allele of a gene in the final sequence or both the alleles (in case of diploid) and how does this happen for both the cases?

Comment: @Ramil All DNA fragments in the sample are (theoretically) sequenced, so both alleles of a particular gene will be sequenced, but unless we already have the paternal and maternal sequences as a reference, there is no way to know if the **G** came from the mother or father. The whole point of my answer (and the last full paragraph) is that the final product is a *single* sequence, with electronic "pointers" indicating areas of heterozygosity, such as the **G→T** difference. However, we can't tell which original chromosome the **G** was on vs. the **T**.

Comment: @MattDMo If both the alleles of the genes are sequenced, how do we get a single sequence for each gene? And the heterozygosity you mentioned, is it with respect to the reference genome?

Comment: @Ramil Differences between alleles are generally very slight when it comes to the DNA sequence - perhaps a few or only a single base difference. I already explained how these differences are detected and reported in the final sequence. Depending on the read length of the instrument, you may *not* be able to show that multiple differences are in the same allele - you'd need a different technology such as RNA-Seq for that. I used the term heterozygosity to refer to the difference between the two alleles possibly present in the sample.

Comment: @MattDMo You mean the forward and the reverse strand that you mentioned gives the difference and the final sequence is the average?

Comment: @Ramil No, the forward and reverse strand have nothing to do with determining variations between alleles, they are only used to add more confidence to reads, as they are perfect complements of each other. The final sequence uses [this code](http://www.boekhoff.info/?pid=data&dat=fasta-codes), so in our example instance the base would be reported as a **K** (either **G** or **T**). With a high enough confidence in this call, one can assume that both **G** *and* **T** are present at that locus, meaning two alleles. You can also go back to the original reads and see that ~50% are G and 50% T.

Comment: @MattDMo Ohh! Thanks a lot. Makes sense to me now.